# Convert to integer with all decimal places (Python)

Tags: python

Example:

My Input is:

```
['00','01', '02', '20', '21']
```

I have tried:

```
[int(i) for i in Input]
```

Which results in:

```
[0, 1, 2, 20, 21]
```

But I'd like the output to be:

```
[00, 01, 02, 20, 21]
```

If I format using:

```
['% 02d'% i for i in Input]
```

To get all the decimal places, my list becomes string being, I'd like the results list to contain integers

Comment: this is imposible, a number is a number, you are playing with its string representation, you need one or another but you cant have both.

Comment: Your need is ill-defined. An integer has no leading 0, that's how it is. It doesn't make sense from a mathematical point of view to insist on it. This is an [xy problem](http://xyproblem.info/). Please tell us what you actually want to do with this list - show some code, and tell us what the final output needs to be.

Comment: Please refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13499182/7662085) answer.

Comment: Numbers starting with '0' is octal in python.

Comment: I agree with @DanielSanchez, if integer needed, will get only 0,1,2,3; else you need to define your own integer class type which can return values in this way, but python will not have such number format.

Comment: @AruneshSingh You mean 0x, and the output still won't show it.

Comment: OMG who upvoted this heresy? Whooo?! XD

Comment: @caroline-d-p-n-barbieri; If you can explain your context, as why you need 01,02,... you may get better solution i guess...?

Comment: I need all the positions because I'm working with ternary logic.This logic is similar to binary, where all bits are required.

Comment: @CarolineD.P.N.Barbieri You should've included it in the question. Could you parse them as 3-base numbers (`int('10', base=3)`), and process them not minding internal representation? You have to write some code to convert them back to `str` though.

Answer (score 4):

Integers in python cannot have leading zeros. You can store those numbers as `str` converting them to `int` as you need those as integers.

Looks like OP wants to work with 3-base numbers, these could be converted from `str` to `int` like this:

```
>>> print(int('10', base=3))
3
```

#### Just for information:

(I won't delete this section as there're comments related to it)

Number literals with leading zero are considered 8-base numbers:

```
>>> print(013)
11
```

Comment: but above example list having 20,21 as sample input. so is it, should be considered as base 10 value? and 01, 02, are should be considered 8-base values?

Comment: @Haranadh I've added 8-base example just for additional information, it is not applicable in this case

Comment: but the expectation was different, owner of question wants as integer, for 01, 02,  20 ,21 all values. to be converted in same way.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot store integer values with leading zeros:

```
>>> x = 005
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    x = 005
          ^
SyntaxError: invalid token
>>> x = 5
```

In Python, like in most programming language, integer values are used to store a number, but not to define how this number will be displayed later. Leading zero are used for printing purpose only.

Answer (score 0):

If your expectation is to do operations on digits, then you are looking for similar to following:

```
get_tens = lambda val: int(int(val)/10)
get_100s = lambda val: int(int(val)/100)

def main():
    vals = ['00', '01', '21', '32', '03']
    for i in vals:
        print get_tens(i)
        # do the operation you want on returned value instead of printing.

        print get_100s(i)
        # do the operation you want on returned value instead of printing.

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

See If this can help!